# Issue with multi-project C# solution?

Tags: c#, .net

So I've seen hundreds of developers organise their solutions into multiple projects, they'll usually have a main project which is just their application name, then a few others, something like below.

```
-- AppName
-- AppName.API
-- AppName.Controllers
-- AppName.Core
```

I'm having a problem understanding this, I can't see how it works. Let's say I have a project called `AppName.Game` which holds the game files for my game emulator. Lets say I need to initiate some kind of game handler to begin the game cycling, I'll need a reference in `AppName` to `AppName.Game`.

That's okay, I can do that. The problem comes when I can't reference `AppName` in `AppName.Game` because I've already referenced it in the opposite direction. What if I **need** to reference `AppName` in `AppName.Game` for something serious, such as to be able to access the Logger class?

I don't see how people make this structure work, is there a work about? Common practice? Can anyone help me out with this, it's driving me crazy.

Some people say make ANOTHER project called `AppName.Common`, but is this really the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Your Logger class would go into a project that both AppName and AppName.Game could reference. AppName.Common seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Move the common classes to another project, maybe `AppName.Core`

Comment: This is way too broad for an answer. The short answer is to organize things in a way that you only have 1-way references.

Comment: It's not broad as I asked for the common practice, that's simply one answer. Thanks for the idea @RonBeyer I think the best option is to just move all the common classes to `AppName.Common`

Answer (score 1):

You already hit on the solution; you need a common project that everyone can reference (but doesn't reference any of your projects).

`*.Common` is a standard name for those; `*.Core` is also reasonable unless using .NET Core

Comment: `(but doesn't reference any of your projects).`, what if I need to reference `AppName.API` for an interface?

Comment: @serialize Why can't you put the interface in AppName.Common?